# mysql response by column name

Tags: php, mysql

When we select data from mysql we receive respond in array with column name value pair but we receive duplicated data. This is what I mean:

We have example table with following data

```
col_a    | col_b
_________________
val1     | rec1
```

This is our request:

```
$take=$dbc->prepare("select * from example");
$take->execute();
$takel=$take->fetch();
```

And this is output of $takel:

```
Array (
[col_a] => val1
[0] => val1
[col_b] => rec1
[1] => rec1
)
```

This is what I want as output:

```
Array (
[col_a] => val1
[col_b] => rec1
)
```

Comment: what is the code what you used? I think, you need to use fetch_assoc instead of fetch_array.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I am using PDO, I will update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fetch assoc:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT col_a, col_b FROM example");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: YES, this is what I want. Thank you a lot. I had google it but I did not know exact what I am looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Where is the PHP Code? Try to use:

$result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result);

$result_array = mysql_fetch_array($query_result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

Comment: I use PDO and I had update question. BTW mysql_* is deprecated and not safe for use.